# Is it okay to suggest doing extra contract/overtime projects at work?

Tags: contracting, overtime, websites

Work as a junior web developer for a smallish software company.

The company is currently looking for an agency to design them a new website. We don't have the capacity to do this internally.

Is it appropriate for me to investigate being hired outside work/getting paid overtime to do this project? Obviously, I'd expect to have to bid for the project, and understand that I wouldn't necessarily get the contact.

I also don't want any conflict of interest between my day job and this extra project, alongside no IP violations, and get that people might be worried about my day job suffering as a result of taking on extra work.

I don't have too much industry experience (so perhaps wouldn't get the contract anyway, if I were allowed to bid), so I don't know if this kind of thing happens.

So my questions are:

- Is this kind of thing appropriate?
- If so, do you think it would negatively influence my relationship with the company?
- Is there anything else I should consider?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything else to consider? How about the impact on your health? If you get the contract, you're looking at doing your day job, going home (or maybe not?), then starting your second job in pretty much the same line of work. This is a quick road to burnout and all the health (physical and mental) problems that come with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd fancy it as a contract but but I'd certainly discuss with your manager if there is the chance to do overtime in this area. I'd argue that it would keep some skills and knowledge in house which is good for the company. At worst they will say no but you'll sound like you're keen with some good ideas.

Comment: @matthelliwell At really worst is they agree for the OP to do the work and set a deadline and then don't offer *any* extra renumeration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would broach the subject in passing rather than make much of it.

"I reckon I could handle that job boss, it would just mean a bunch of extra hours."

And then move forwards from the response. I wouldn't apply for it. I'd only take it if it was all in-house and above board. So if the boss thought it was a good idea then we could discuss it more seriously in terms of remuneration etc.